# Pegar o nome da Imagem na URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url

Preciso pegar o nome da imagem na url.

```
/data/data/com.intel.appx.IZICondominios.xwalk15/files/_pictures/picture_006.jpg
```

Preciso que volte:

> picture_006.jpg

O modelo de URL não é fixo, cada situação pode mudar. Pode ter mais ou menos pastas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse problema tem duas partes:

- ler a url
- extrair o nome do ficheiro

#### ler a url:

Se não tens já o url numa string podes usar `location.pathname` ou mesmo `location.href`. Isso vai dar uma string que podes usar no próximo passo

#### extrair o nome do ficheiro

Podes fazer isto com RegEx ou com `.split`.

Usando regex a regra que procuras é uma string que esteja no final do url (usando `location.pathname`) e que contenha `.jpg`. Podes fazer isso assim ([exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/fE5eZ5/2)):

```
/([^\/\\]+.jpg)/
```

Usando `.split` basta retirar o ultimo elemento da array que o `split` gera partindo a string com `str.split(/[\/\\]/)`.

### Exemplos:

- #### com regex

Exemplo que faz um log na consola caso não encontre...

```
var url = location.pathname;
var match = url.match(/[^\/\\]+.jpg/);
if (!match) console.log('não encontrou...');
else alert(match[0]);
```

- #### com split

Exemplo que faz um log na consola caso não encontre...

```
var url = location.pathname;
var partes = url.split(/[\/\\]/);
var img = partes.pop();
if (!img) console.log('não encontrou...');
else alert(img);
```

Answer (score 4):

Um exemplo usando o método `lastIndexOf()`

```
url = '/data/data/com.intel.appx.IZICondominios.xwalk15/files/_pictures/picture_006.jpg';
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
console.log(filename);
```

Comment: Resolveu meu problema! Uma pena essa resposta estar em último colocado na página. Testei todas soluções até chegar nessa que é a mais simples.

Answer (score 3):

Se o nome da sua imagem tiver sempre esse mesmo número de caractéres, você pode fazer isso:

```js
var url = "/data/data/com.intel.appx.IZICondominios.xwalk15/files/_pictures/picture_006.jpg";

document.write(url.substring(url.length-15, url.length));
```

Mas caso quem tenha o mesmo número de caractéres seja o restante de sua url, você pode fazer assim:

```js
   var url = "/data/data/com.intel.appx.IZICondominios.xwalk15/files/_pictures/picture_006.jpg";

document.write(url.substring(65, url.length));
```

**Mas se os dois forem inconstantes:**

```js
var url = "/data/data/com.intel.appx.IZICondominios.xwalk15/files/_pictures/picture_006.jpg";
var n;
for(var i = url.length; i > 0; i--){
 if(url.charAt(i) == "/"){
   n = i;
  break;
 }
}

document.write(url.substring(n+1, url.length));
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta. Esqueci de falar uma coisa. A URL não é fixa. Ela pode ser diferente em cada situação.

Comment: Mas o tamanho do nome da imagem também muda? Por exemplo, há vezes que é "picture_006.jpg" e há vezes que é "image1.jpg"? Ou é sempre nessa formatação "picture_005.jpg" ou "picture_190.jpg"?

Comment: Atualmente estou fazendo a parte que fica padrão ``picture_001.jpg, picture_002.jpg, ...``, mas vai ter uma parte ainda que irei criar que terá o nome do arquivo indefinido.

Comment: Acho que o correto seria fazer sem seguir o padrão do nome e sim um nome aleatório. ``picture_006.jpg``, ``image1.jpg``, ``tiago.png``, ...

Comment: Editei com uma solução que serve para qualquer tamanho de url e qualquer tamanho do nome da sua imagem. Mas o nome deve estar no final da url.

Comment: Veja se lhe serve.